# How to change exported property through MEF?

Tags: export, mef

I'm studying MEF, and try to use Export attribute to export a property, and import it in an other class.
But my problem is that I want to change this property and the other class can import a new value.
For example,

```
[Export]
public class A{
    [Import("Notes")]
    public string Description{get;set;}
}

[Export]
public class B{
    [Export("Notes")]
    public string Text{get;set;}
}
```

I want once I change the Text of class B, the A.Description can get changed too.

So, how can I implement this?
Any good idea?

Answer (score 0):

This approach would work for most reference type but not with string which is immutable. This means that after you change the value of B.Text, the objects referenced by A.Description and B.Text will no longer be the same (you can use [Object.ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to test this).

One way to do what you are after using MEF is to export/import a method instead of the property:

```
[Export]
public class A
{
    public string Description { get { return GetDescription(); } }        

    [Import("GetNotes")]
    Func<string> GetDescription;
}

[Export]
public class B
{        
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Export("GetNotes")]
    string GetText()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Finally note that there are other ways to do this. The most common in .NET is with events.